# PostgreSQL installation dockerfile

Tags: postgresql, installation, dockerfile

I was trying to create docker image of postgresql installation from sources, however, I have got [some errors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47623017/postgresql-docker-image-build-errors) I do not know how to fix. And I was wondering whether there is an alternative way to build this image without using standard postgres docker image?

I would be grateful for any resources and help!

Answer (score 1):

Regarding the errors that you are facing I have shared the answer [here.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47623017/postgresql-docker-image-build-errors/47632353#47632353)

As you have asked for docker image, all the **open source docker images are stored at https://hub.docker.com which is a central repository for public images**. You can search any docker image that you are specifically looking for. Even look for Dockerfiles, available for most of the images, for these images to get an Idea of how the application is built.

**You can try this postgres docker image which is available here : https://hub.docker.com/_/postgres/**